# yii2: How do I deploy my application to live server?

Tags: php, error-handling, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I just copied all my files which are working ok on localhost to my server [here](http://www.254bet.com).

Here I receive a 403:

> Forbidden - Access to this resource on the server is denied!

I believe this is due to the fact that I have deployed the application as local application. I cannot find information about changing main and main-local config files.
 
Both of these files are the same ones that come with the advanced application.
 
What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the httpd user have read access to the files? Does anything show up in the php error log?

Comment: @Mike the only thing appearing on my error_log is PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/.../index.php on line 3

Comment: What about the other question?

Comment: issue a `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/mywebsite` (or whatever the location of your website is) command on your website's directory to eliminate the problem with permissions. of course you dont want to ever keep it that way.

Comment: @Mike I did what the above user2914191 suggested but still experience the same issue, is that what you mean by httpd user?

Comment: note that no configuration file update is required in this case, changing file permissions and ensuring that php5.4 is used usually works fine.